# How do i connect my domain name to a Docker container running a Ghost blog

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, hosting, ghost

What i have done:

- Bought a domain name with Dreamhost.
- Redirected said domain names DNS A record to the ip of my docker environment.
- Set up a Docker environment with portainer, running a container with the latest version of the GHOST blogging platform. The platform works, and i can access it through a specific port appended to the host IP address of the Docker envrionment as always.

Now, i'd like to redirect my visitors to a specific domain name, but i've read around the internet and documentation for Docker, but my biggest problem is i'm not sure what to search for.

From what i gather, i will need Nginx to route people from the IP address to the correct port. Any help would be great, as i'm new to Docker and really want to learn.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask for  help pointing DNS to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repo which completly help your rquirement with nginx,  Here is the link,
 [Docker compose NGINX - Reverse proxy with SSL](https://github.com/JinnaBalu/docker-nginx-ssl)